# Which OAuth 2.0 flows does Swagger support?

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger, swagger-ui

OAuth 2.0 has the following grant types (flows):

- `authorization_code`
- `implicit`
- `password`
- `client_credentials`
- `refresh_token`

Then which of these flows does Swagger support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenAPI/Swagger supports the four OAuth flows defined by [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3). The keywords and the corresponding OAuth 2 flows are:

- `accessCode` (OpenAPI 2.0) or `authorizationCode` (OpenAPI 3.0) - authorization code flow.
- `implicit` - implicit flow.
- `password` - resource owner password credentials flow.
- `application` (OpenAPI 2.0) or `clientCredentials` (OpenAPI 3.0) - client credentials flow.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to go with the OpenAPI 3.0 specification instead of using Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0. It has a lot less design flaws, even if the ramp up might be a little more difficult. Things like https://editor.swagger.io help a lot as well.